# Add to Cart button disappears for products with custom options

Tags: custom-options, addtocart

Please bear with me as I'm fairly new to Magento. I'm using v1.9.3.2 Community Edition.

So I've bought the Shoppy Store theme on Themeforest and managed to install it but sadly now products with custom options (like size for t-shirts) do not show the 'Add to Cart' (Buy It Now) button on the front-end.

See two different examples here:

Without Buy It Now button: http://www.mytrade.mu/hip-hop-plain-shirt.html
With Buy It Now button: http://www.mytrade.mu/catalog/product/view/id/244/s/big-hair-spinning-brush/category/2/

If I remove the custom options for the product, the Buy It Now button reappears.

Unfortunately the theme developers haven't been of much help.

I'm pretty much at my wits' end here. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While checking the links you provided, i found there is some custom js written for price box. This may be a issue, Check these js function code.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Please follow this url-

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ulud3ncJXo-tpoHLEh_D4hIjZm8HvGB4pvQaHeSNbwU/edit?usp=sharing